# Duplicar linhas a partir de um intervalo de valores entre duas colunas PANDAS

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

##### Como exemplo, tenho esse Dataframe:

```
df = {
    'col1': ['a', 'b', 'c'],
    'col2': [1, 4, 5],
    'col3': [1, 6, 9],
}

  col1  col2  col3
0    a     1     1
1    b     4     6
2    c     5     9
```

##### Preciso deste resultado:

```
  col1  col2  col3  col4
0    a     1     1     1
1    b     4     6     4
2    b     4     6     5
3    b     4     6     6
4    c     5     9     5
5    c     5     9     6
6    c     5     9     7
7    c     5     9     8
8    c     5     9     9

podendo até excluir a col2 e col3:

  col1  col4
0    a     1
1    b     4
2    b     5
3    b     6
4    c     5
5    c     6
6    c     7
7    c     8
8    c     9
```

Ou seja, preciso comparar duas colunas(col2 e col3) sendo a primeira o valor inicial e a segunda o valor final, assim, duplicar as linhas de acordo com esse intervalo repetindo todos os valores e alocando em uma nova coluna(col4) todos os valores em ordem.

Em resumo, uma nova coluna contendo o range encontrado entre as duas colunas, repetindo os demais valores.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primeiro crie uma array com a subtração entre **col3 e col2**. 
Esses valores corresponderão ao número de vezes que cada linha do DF será duplicado com os comandos `reindex` e `repeat`. 
Com o DF expandido, é só criar a nova coluna que receberá os valores da **col2** somados ao retorno do `groupby` com `cumcount`, e por ultimo é só dropar as colunas desejadas com `drop`. 
Segue o código:

```
temp_var = df['col3'].sub(df['col2']) + 1 
df = df.reindex(df.index.repeat(temp_var))
df['col4'] = df['col2'] + df.groupby(['col1','col2']).cumcount()
df = df.drop(columns=['col2','col3'])

df.head(15)
#saida:
    col1    col4
0   a       1
1   b       4
1   b       5
1   b       6
2   c       5
2   c       6
2   c       7
2   c       8
2   c       9
```

Comment: Perfeito Terry, muito obrigado! Estava me batendo com isso e sua resposta resolveu o problema!

Comment: Que bom @LeandroMagalhãesPadilha. Se você puder assinalar minha resposta como aceita clicando no "V" ali do lado esquerdo para encerrar o tópico, eu agradeço